# pandas split column ,keep the delimiter and create the new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have some chinese data like this:

```
col
香港特別行政區 九龍 彩虹 彩虹邨錦雲樓99樓99室
```

I want to split the col to be:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7
香港特別行政區,九龍,彩虹,彩虹邨,錦雲樓,99樓,99室
```

I have tried to split this but I fail.

I have tried:

```
for i, s in enumerate(df['col']):
    a = re.split('([邨樓室]*)', s)
    print(a)
```

The result:

```
['香港特別行政區 九龍 彩虹 彩虹', '邨', '錦雲', '樓', '99', '樓', '99', '室', '']
```

This code can split by '邨樓室'(delimiter) and keep the delimiter but the result isn't I want. And I can't split by space and create the new column by split data in this case.

I am stuck. I need some help please.